# How to stop calculating values on click event if there is no change in winform fields

Tags: c#, winforms

I am newbie to programming. I am learning on my own and it's the end of my first week. I am creating a C# form to calculate insurance sum against user's requirements. On clicking Calculate Insurance Price button it calculates the total sum and shows it in TotalLabel. The form calculates and shows total accurately but only for the first time. For example if its 325.5 $ first time, if I click Calculate Insurance Price button again without changing credential in form like age, country, sick etc. it recalculates and shows 600$ and on every click it recalculates.

I want to only calculate the total sum in case any field was changed. If there are no changes in credentials it should not recalculate and if it recalculates TotalLabel value should not change which is not in my case.

Here is my code. Please suggest what's the mistake.

```
public partial class Mainform : Form
{

   decimal baseinsuranceprice = 50.5m;
    public Mainform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Insuranceprice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ag = int.Parse(Agetextbox.Text);
        age(ag, baseinsuranceprice);
        string coun = Countrycombobox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        country(coun, baseinsuranceprice);
        premiuminsurance(baseinsuranceprice);
        Noclaim(baseinsuranceprice);
        Sick(baseinsuranceprice);
        decimal minimuminsuranceprice = 80.5m;
        if (baseinsuranceprice < minimuminsuranceprice)
        baseinsuranceprice = minimuminsuranceprice;
        TotalLabel.Text = "$" + baseinsuranceprice.ToString();
    }
    public decimal age(int a, decimal b)
    {
        if (a > 30)
        {
            baseinsuranceprice = baseinsuranceprice + 50;
        }
        else
        {
            baseinsuranceprice = baseinsuranceprice + 100;
        }
        return baseinsuranceprice;
    }
    public decimal country(string a, decimal c)
    {
        if (a == "USA")
        {
            baseinsuranceprice = baseinsuranceprice + 40;
        }
        else
        {
            baseinsuranceprice = baseinsuranceprice + 50;
        }
        return baseinsuranceprice;
    }
    public decimal premiuminsurance(decimal f)
    {
        if (PremiumInsuranceRadioButtonYes.Checked)
            baseinsuranceprice = baseinsuranceprice + 100;

        return baseinsuranceprice;
    }
    public decimal Noclaim(decimal g)
    {
        if (NoClaimDiscountRadioButtonYes.Checked)
            baseinsuranceprice -= 25;
        else if (NoClaimDiscountRadioButtonNo.Checked)
            baseinsuranceprice += 50;
        return baseinsuranceprice;
    }
    public decimal Sick(decimal h)
    {
        if (SickCoverRadioButtonYes.Checked)
            baseinsuranceprice += 50;

        return baseinsuranceprice;
    }  
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlqEN.png)

Comment: Time to step through the code in your debugger.  Place a debugging breakpoint on the first line of your click handler method.  When the debugger pauses there, step through each line of code and observe the resulting changes to the variables.  On the second click, where does the calculation first go wrong?  What value was different than what you expect?  Why is it different the second time?  At a glance it *looks like* you're updating `baseinsuranceprice`, but why?  Shouldn't that value be static and unchanging between calculations?

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your code is easier than you think

Comment: Disable the click event...once the button is pressed...and then enable it when there are other text box changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your most significant mistake is that you are holding

```
decimal baseinsuranceprice = 50.5m;
```

as a field of your *Mainform* class. This is why you are getting new result every time you hit the button with the same parameters (after first calculation *baseinsuranceprice* is not 50.5m anymore).

The easiest solution is to "reset" this value to initial *50.5m* one before every calculation.

My suggestion is to implement your price calculating algorithm as a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) (maybe you even want to have it as a separate class, and maybe you'd like to write some tests for it), so you only give initial parameters to your function / class and it calculates you the result.

This way you won't have any dependency on your form's state. Moreover, in case you need to keep some base insurance price in your system, it's better to have it as a constant or even as a value read from the configuration.

In my opinion, there is nothing bad in recalculating the value if this calculation doesn't take too much time. In your case this is fine to launch the calculation on every click.

Comment: Thanks All. Problem Resolved, I reset the value of baseinsurancepremium after every calculation and on click event I put a check that if flag a is true then do calculations else retain the previous value and flag a gets updated in selection changed and text change and checked changed events of my form control...... 
I know I over-killed the problem but I am very new to this world 
Thanks All